# Not able to restart Jenkins - Memory error

Tags: java, jenkins

I am getting below error while restarting Jenkins.

```
INFO: Ready to receive data from Gerrit: Gerrit-QA
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: INFO: os::commit_memory(0x00000007b1480000, 246939648, 0) failed; error='C
annot allocate memory' (errno=12)
#
# There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.
# Native memory allocation (mmap) failed to map 246939648 bytes for committing reserved memory.
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /usr/share/tomcat6/hs_err_pid29653.log
```

How I resolve this ?

Comment: Free up some memory?

Comment: the command is correct sync | sudo tee /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches or swapoff -a && swapon -a ?

Comment: No, that only clears caches. You have too much memory allocated--such as too many programs running.